# Using the same variable for different conditions in conditionalPanel

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like to set up a min, max, and range conditional panel. When "min" is selected, only the one box is shown, the other when "max" is selected, and both when "range" is selected. If the user enters a value for "min", I would like it to carry over if they toggle to "range".

Not working code below. Thanks!

```
library('shiny')
library('shinydashboard')

ui <- dashboardPage( title="sample code",
   dashboardHeader( title="sample code",disable=TRUE ),
   dashboardSidebar(
      box( width=12,title="sample sidebar",solidHeader=TRUE,status="warning",background = "black",
           tags$style(".skin-blue .sidebar a:link { color:orange; } a:visited {color:green;}"),
      )
   ),      
   dashboardBody(
      uiOutput("boxes")
   )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
   
   output$boxes <- renderUI({
      lapply( 1:5, function( inputRow ) {
         fluidRow(
                  box( width=5,
                       radioButtons( paste0( 'row', inputRow, 'Param' ), 'Set a:' , inline=TRUE, selected = "min",  c("min"="min", "max"="max", "range"="range", "none"="none")),
                       
                       conditionalPanel(condition = paste0( "input.", 'row', inputRow, "Param != 'none'") ),
      
                       conditionalPanel(condition = paste0( "input.", 'row', inputRow, "Param == 'min'" ),
                                        numericInput( paste0(  'row', inputRow,'MinLimit' ), label="Minimum", value = NULL, width = "90%") ),

                       conditionalPanel(condition = paste0( "input.", 'row', inputRow, "Param == 'max'" ),
                                        numericInput( paste0(  'row', inputRow,'MaxLimit' ), label="Maximum", value = NULL, width = "90%") ),
                       
                       conditionalPanel(condition = paste0( "input.", 'row', inputRow, "Param == 'range'" ),
                                        numericInput( paste0(  'row', inputRow,'MinLimit' ), label="Minimum", value = NULL, width = "90%"),
                                        numericInput( paste0(  'row', inputRow,'MaxLimit' ), label="Maximum", value = NULL, width = "90%") )
                  ),
                  box( width=4,
                       renderValueBox({
                          valueBox( eval( paste0(  'input$row', inputRow,'MinLimit' ) ), subtitle="i am stuck", icon = icon("list"), color = "purple" )
                       })                  
                  )
            )
         } )
   })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: So - what's the problem exactly?

Comment: Thanks for asking. If I select "min" and enter a value, then select "range", that value isn't copied over into the input box. Additionally, while I can access the "min" value through its variable name, the value entered into the minimum range (which has the same variable name) is inaccessible.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Please check my answer..

Comment: Great question (why am I doing this in renderUI?). I'm doing it in renderUI because that's how the example I modeled it on worked. I'm using the lapply to build a series of boxes, each of which has an image, a static (but calculated) table, several inputs, and several valueBoxes. These boxes are created dynamically based on selections in the dashboard sidebar. The results of the all of the lapply boxes are aggregated and displayed in a box at the top. I discovered last night that I probably should have used a module, but I'm still reading about that.

Comment: Yep - sounds like modules would fit for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the above code is, that you are trying to create multiple `numericInput`'s with the same id. It is sufficient to create it once and adapt the JS condition, concerning when to display it.

Please check the following:

```
library('shiny')
library('shinydashboard')

ui <- dashboardPage( title="sample code",
                     dashboardHeader( title="sample code",disable=TRUE ),
                     dashboardSidebar(
                       box( width=12,title="sample sidebar",solidHeader=TRUE,status="warning",background = "black",
                            tags$style(".skin-blue .sidebar a:link { color:orange; } a:visited {color:green;}"),
                       )
                     ),      
                     dashboardBody(
                       uiOutput("boxes")
                     )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$boxes <- renderUI({
    lapply( 1:5, function( inputRow ) {
      fluidRow(
        box( width=5,
             radioButtons( paste0( 'row', inputRow, 'Param' ), 'Set a:' , inline=TRUE, selected = "min",  c("min"="min", "max"="max", "range"="range", "none"="none")),
             conditionalPanel(condition = sprintf( "input.row%sParam != 'none'", inputRow) ),
             conditionalPanel(condition = sprintf("(input.row%sParam == 'min' || input.row%sParam == 'range')", inputRow, inputRow),
                              numericInput( paste0(  'row', inputRow,'MinLimit' ), label="Minimum", value = NULL, width = "90%") ),
             conditionalPanel(condition = sprintf("(input.row%sParam == 'max' || input.row%sParam == 'range')", inputRow, inputRow),
                              numericInput( paste0(  'row', inputRow,'MaxLimit' ), label="Maximum", value = NULL, width = "90%") )
        ),
        box(width=4,
            renderValueBox({
              inputIDmin <- paste0('row', inputRow,'MinLimit')
              inputIDmax <- paste0('row', inputRow,'MaxLimit')
              valueBox(sprintf("Min: %s | Max: %s", input[[inputIDmin]], input[[inputIDmax]]), subtitle="i am no longer stuck", icon = icon("list"), color = "purple" )
            })                  
        )
      )
    } )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfectly. That's why you're a wizard. I still need to figure out how to display the result in my valueBox, but that's a different question. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! Let me know if there is a follow-up question. Cheers

Comment: For future readers: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64032501/how-to-format-an-active-valuebox-in-a-dynamically-generated-conditionalpanel-in) it is.

Comment: Dang. Now that I have this implemented I have one last question: This works exactly as I asked--if I enter a min value and then go to range, that min value is carried over. But if I go from min to max (or range to max) I would like to delete the min. Similarly, delete the max when going from max to min (or range to min). I'd also like to delete all the values if I select "none". Is that possible or do I just need to work around it?

Comment: Of course that's possible. You can use  `updateNumericInput` to modify the current value displayed. It requires some additional logic to be implemented. I think it would be best if you create a follow up question.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to use updateNumericInput, but I was able to incorporate the necessary logic later in the program so I'm all set. Thanks again!